# Creating Active Directory on an EC2 box

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, amazon-ec2

So I have Active Directory set up on a Windows Server 2008 Amazon EC2 server. Its set up correctly I think, I never got any errors with it. Just to test that I got it all set up correctly, I have a Windows 7 Professional virtual machine set up on my network to join to AD. I set the VM to use the Active Directory box as its DNS server. I type in my domain to join it, but I get the following error:

```
DNS was successfully queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate a domain controller for domain "ad.win.chigs.me":

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.ad.win.chigs.me

The following domain controllers were identified by the query:
ip-0af92ac4.ad.win.chigs.me


However no domain controllers could be contacted.

Common causes of this error include:

- Host (A) or (AAAA) records that map the names of the domain controllers to their IP addresses are missing or contain incorrect addresses.

- Domain controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or are not running.
```

It seems that I can talk to Active Directory, but when I'm trying to contact the Domain Controller, its giving a private IP to connect to, at least thats what I can make out of it. Here are some nslookup results.

```
> win.chigs.me
Server:  ec2-184-73-35-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Address:  184.73.35.150

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    ec2-184-73-35-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Address:  10.249.42.196
Aliases:  win.chigs.me

> ad.win.chigs.me
Server:  ec2-184-73-35-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Address:  184.73.35.150

Name:    ad.win.chigs.me
Address:  10.249.42.196
```

win.chigs.me and ad.win.chigs.me are CNAME's pointing to my EC2 box. Any idea what I need to do so that I can join my virtual machine to the EC2 Active Directory set up I have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enable all the necessary ports in the security group? See [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/rexiology/archive/2006/04/05/89389.aspx) post...

Comment: Yup, all of the ports necessary are opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that without VPN. Your EC2 instance is using private IP address within EC2. While you're trying to connect from an external machine to LAN. So the Workstation attempts to ping the LAN IP of the EC2 DC which it can't reach.

You need the workstation/server to be on public IPs both, or both in the same LAN, or VPN between workstation LAN/WAN and server LAN.

Comment: I have a VPN setup, but its still not joining :(